# Cascading logging in Python - Are there pitfalls i dont see?

Tags: python, logging, production

I spent a lot of time in finding a setup for logging that works best for our projects. Our team is quite young and standards are establishing only now. We want to have well formatted logs that are taken care of in different handlers. That should be true if the whole application is started from main as well as a sub-package is run and debugged on its own. For that, we put together the following file structure:

```
project_folder
¦- main.py
¦- package_a
¦  ¦- module_1
¦  ¦- module_2
¦- logging_setup.py
```

With that, every file (main, module_1, etc.) has the following two lines before the rest of the import statements:

```
import logging, logging_setup
logger = logging_setup.setup("module_1") if not logging.getLogger().hasHandlers() else logging.getLogger()
```

This checks if its "parent" has set up a logger. If not, it creates its own according to logging_setup. As an example, it would create its own file with the name appendix "module_1" for recognition. Foldercreation for the file is also handled in logging_setup, so reusability should be given as long as logging_setup is present. And as every project needs some form of boiler plate code for logging, this could develop into a standard of our projects. This also works with pytest as it creates his own logger, which would be used the same way.

Are there pitfalls i am overseeing or does a way exist that makes it easier maintainable when projects *really* go up in scale?

Thank you for your insights!

Comment: You could have `logging_setup` wrap the `getLogger` call, so the boilerplate reduces to `import logging_setup; logger = logging_setup.getLogger(__name__)`. Then it'll probably be as maintainable as it gets, because there is no unnecessary duplication anymore.

Comment: Also, the common practice is to have each package create its own logger: `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` instead of `logger = logging.getLogger()` which would use the root logger for everything. Use the parent-child hierarchy to your advantage.

Comment: This question might be more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Thomas, the question needs much more context for [codereview.se]. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on codereview. I wasn't aware of that platform and it probably would have helped in a specific research on logging.

Comment: I wonder if we could think of a question title that better describes the content here, for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there pitfalls i am overseeing or does a way exist that makes it easier maintainable when projects really go up in scale?

Yes, there are problems with this arrangement at any scale beyond "ad-hoc one-off script that won't be used frequently or maintained/developed by multiple people".

---

You do not define what "set up" means, but it sounds like you are talking about creating handlers and formatters, and attaching them to individual loggers.

It's normally **not** a good practice to "set up" formatted and handlers at the top level of every module in this sense.

The intended usage of the logging framework is so that logging a message is, by itself, cheap and free of side effects. The logging system is intended to be a black box, into which libraries dump messages, deliberately unaware of where they will be routed or how they will be handled.

If you are writing a "library", that is as far as it should go! Log handling and formatting is meant to be controlled by the user that is importing your code. Their logging to setup might be very different from what you anticipate, and your imposition of a particular set of handlers and for matters might make it impossible for other people to use this library.

If you are writing an "application", you don't really need to worry about other users importing your modules, so you can get away with a set up like this. However, I would still suggest that it is not good practice. Among other reasons, it's usually a good idea to write your applications as if they were the composition of many libraries, and to avoid interleaving "application-level" logic throughout.

As you also seem to be discovering with your attempt to write some kind of fallback logic, performing application setup when a module is imported means that you have poor control over when that setup is performed. You will spend a lot of time writing and debugging fallback logic. This is a waste of your effort, and it's not necessary because there is a better way to do things.

There also seem to be a couple of misunderstandings about the logging system reflected in your design.

Logging is "hierarchical", in that logger `a.b` is considered a "parent" of `a.b.c`, and my default log messages are *propagated upward* to their parents*. This means that, if you configure a handler for `a.b`, then messages logged to `a.b.c` will also be handled by the handler attached to `a.b`. You should not need to attach a handler to both `a.b` and `a.b.c`; you will get duplicate log messages if you do!

Moreover, your `log_setup` function appears to obtain a logger that is scoped to the current module, but your "fallback" code obtains the *root* logger, the special logger with no name (`''`) that is considered the parent of all other loggers.

My recommendation is to only call `logging.getLogger(__name__)` inside each module, and to configure all required handlers and formatters only inside `main.py`. this is standard practice how it is, and hopefully this answer provides some insight into why that is so.

Comment: Thank you very much for your indepth explanation. I understand all your points, except the one for the 'hierarchical' part. I am aware that logging is hierarchical and exactly that is what i take advantage of here. A new logger including handlers only get set up if its parent doesn't already provide one. If it does, my solution doesn't diverge much from your recommendation. I have not noticed double logging with this setup yet. Let me know what i'm not seeing here.

Comment: I think shadowtalker is just saying you don't need to do all that - e.g. you could just provide handlers at the root logger, and propagation takes care of the other loggers automatically. shadowtalker's proposal is simpler and is the practice recommended in the official logging documentation.

Comment: @kesslmar in addition to what Vinay said above, my post also admonishes against setting up handlers unconditionally at the top of each module. You should set up the handlers in `main.py` instead, only when you actually need them. Modules themselves should not be responsible for handling or formatting log messages.

Comment: Oh wow, @VinaySajip you are the author of the logging howto! Thanks! Is there a section in that document that describes this practice? I was just looking through its contents and didn't see one.

Comment: Not sure exactly which practice you're referring to. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial mentions the use of `__name__` early on, configuring logging for a library is discussed in https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library, and things to avoid are addressed in https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#patterns-to-avoid